# Accelerating some kind of dataframe stretching in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

I have the following travel booking data:

```r
library(dplyr)
bookings <- data.frame(Route = 'AB', DepartureMonth = rep(yearmonth("2013-11"),9),
           EffectiveFrom = c(rep(yearmonth("2013-07"),5), c(rep(yearmonth("2013-08"),4))),
           EffectiveTo = c("2013-08", "2013-09", "2013-10", "2013-11", "2199-12",
                           "2013-09", "2013-10", "2013-11", "2199-12"),
           ConfirmedBooking = c(16, 6, 8, 15, 15, 76, 95, 81, 202)) %>%
  mutate(EffectiveTo = yearmonth(EffectiveTo))
bookings
```

```r
Route DepartureMonth EffectiveFrom    EffectiveTo ConfirmedBooking
AB      2013 nov.       2013 july       2013 aug.       16
AB      2013 nov.       2013 july       2013 sept.      6
AB      2013 nov.       2013 july       2013 oct.       8
AB      2013 nov.       2013 july       2013 nov.       15
AB      2013 nov.       2013 july       2199 dec.       15
AB      2013 nov.       2013 aug.       2013 sept.      76
AB      2013 nov.       2013 aug.       2013 oct.       95
AB      2013 nov.       2013 aug.       2013 nov.       81
AB      2013 nov.       2013 aug.       2199 dec.       202
```

I wrote a code to get the number of bookings at the end of a given month prior to departure:

```r
booking_month_decomposition <- function(Route, DepartureMonth, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo, ConfirmedBooking) {
  end_month = if_else(EffectiveTo < DepartureMonth, EffectiveTo, DepartureMonth)
  maxiter = end_month - EffectiveFrom
  
  return(map_dfr(1:maxiter, function(x) data.frame(Route = Route, DepartureMonth=DepartureMonth,
                                                   BookingMonth=EffectiveFrom + x -1,
                                                   ConfirmedBooking=ConfirmedBooking)))
}

bookings %>% pmap_dfr(booking_month_decomposition) %>%
  group_by(Route, DepartureMonth, BookingMonth) %>%
  summarise(ConfirmedBooking = sum(ConfirmedBooking)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```r
Route DepartureMonth BookingMonth   ConfirmedBooking
AB      2013 nov.       2013 july       60  
AB      2013 nov.       2013 aug.       498 
AB      2013 nov.       2013 sept.      416 
AB      2013 nov.       2013 oct.       313
```

The problem is that **the execution of the code takes almost an hour** when I start from a dataframe of 170.000 rows to arrive at a dataframe of 34.000 rows.

The *booking_month_decomposition* function takes too long to run. Am I using the purrr functions wrong?

PS: *The number of bookings was supposed to increase when we get closer to departure, but this cannot be seen because to simplify I shortened the departure dataframe by eliminating bookings starting from September.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping is really not efficient in R so it's better to find a way to avoid it when possible.

For your use case, you can create the column `BookingMonth` containing a vector containing the `seq` of months between `EffectiveFrom` and `end_month` for each rows then unnest that column to duplicate the rows for each month.

You can then filter for when `EffectiveTo` is equal to the `BookingMonth` since `EffectiveTo` is not inclusive then use `group_by` to `sum` the variable `ConfirmedBooking`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tsibble)

bookings = bookings %>%
  mutate(end_month = if_else(EffectiveTo < DepartureMonth, EffectiveTo, DepartureMonth)) %>%
  group_by(Route, EffectiveTo, ConfirmedBooking, DepartureMonth) %>%
  do(
    BookingMonth = seq(from = min(.$EffectiveFrom), to = max(.$end_month), by = 1)
  ) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(EffectiveTo != BookingMonth) %>%
  group_by(Route, DepartureMonth, BookingMonth) %>%
  summarise(ConfirmedBooking = sum(ConfirmedBooking)) %>%
  filter(DepartureMonth != BookingMonth)
```

Comment: Your answer helped me very much. Thanks. Just a little problem of underestimation due to min/max or something else. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Wawv's solution. Very usefull and speed but that did not give the right result for another sample (underestimation of some booking months):

```r
bookings <- data.frame(Route = 'AB',
    DepartureMonth = rep(yearmonth("2013-12"), 2),
    EffectiveFrom = c("2013-08", "2013-09") %>% yearmonth(),
    EffectiveTo = c("2013-11", "2013-11") %>% yearmonth(),
    ConfirmedBooking = 60)
bookings
```

```r
Route   DepartureMonth  EffectiveFrom   EffectiveTo ConfirmedBooking
AB      2013 dec.       2013 aug.       2013 nov.       60
AB      2013 dec.       2013 sept.      2013 nov.       60
```

So I changed a few things:

```r
bookings %>%
    mutate(end_month = if_else(EffectiveTo < DepartureMonth, EffectiveTo, DepartureMonth)) %>%
    group_by(across(!ConfirmedBooking)) %>% # also 'across(everything())'
    mutate(BookingMonth = list(seq(from = EffectiveFrom, to = end_month, by = 1))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    unnest() %>%
    filter(BookingMonth != EffectiveTo,
           BookingMonth != DepartureMonth) %>%
    group_by(Route, DepartureMonth, BookingMonth) %>%
    summarise(ConfirmedBooking = sum(ConfirmedBooking))
```

```r
Route   DepartureMonth  BookingMonth    ConfirmedBooking
AB      2013 dec.       2013 aug.       60
AB      2013 dec.       2013 sept.      120
AB      2013 dec.       2013 oct.       120
```

From @Wawv's code I got:

```r
Route   DepartureMonth  BookingMonth    ConfirmedBooking
AB      2013 dec.       2013 aug.       60
AB      2013 dec.       2013 sept.      60
AB      2013 dec.       2013 oct.       60
```